# ExecutionEngineException when launching new windows in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently developing a piece of software in C# WPF. When I launch a window from my software it works fine in one area of the code, but when called in a different section of code it throws the ExecutionEngineException. I have tried putting a try catch statement around but it isn't going into the catch to display an error.

Below is the code where the window is being opened.

```
private void requestPassword()
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("It looks like this is the first time you have used Boardies Password Manager."
                + "\n\nWould you like to enable a password in order to protect your data?\n\nThis password would need to be entered "
                + "each time you run the software, this ensures others can't access your personal information", "Enable Password",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                new RequestPassword().Show();
            }
            else
            {
                new MainScreen().Show();
            }
        }
```

Either lines inside the if and else display the error for both windows being opened. It is displaying the error on the line of the code when it goes to launch the new window and it calls the InitialiseComponent() method.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Some binding not working? Missing resource dictionaries or something? The problem you posted is too undefined... :/

Comment: There is no data binding or resource dictionaries being loaded. Its using an SQLite Database if that helps to maybe resolve the problem. I've only just started doing development on it and don't understand why it calls from one section of the code but when called from an if statement it then displays the exception.

Comment: Ah and I would check if assemblies in the bin folder of the project where it is breaking are the same version of those where it is working. - and I mean not only direct references, but some other dll that those references are loading.

Comment: ExecutionEngineException cannot be caught, btw. It usually means you are feeding the runtime with something it can't chew :D

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, it was because I was calling of a window first, then calling the class, when I switched it the other way round it worked fine.